# SUMing the results of a COUNT() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is a UNION query required to achieve the following. I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
some_id | some_date
--------------------
5       | 2016-04-03
3       | 2016-04-03
2       | 2016-04-03
5       | 2016-04-03
```

I'd like to get the total number of times we've seen any and all ID for the date `2016-04-03`. So the SUM would be 3 here, with 5 having a count of 2, 3 having a count of 1, 2 having a count of 1.

Is a UNION required to make this work?

This is using MySQL 5.6+

Comment: Is this what you're after? `select some_id, count(*) from yourtable where some_date = '2016-04-03' group by some_id`

Comment: How do you want the result data to be presented? If it is just the total, just a count would do what you want.

Comment: The simple answer: no, you wouldn't use a `union`.

Comment: The total number of *ID*s or the total number of *rows*?  You have four rows, but only three IDs.

Comment: The total number of IDs @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT some_id)
FROM YourTable
WHERE some_date = '2016-04-03'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this requires a `UNION`

```
SELECT some_id, SUM(1) as cnt, some_date
FROM some_table
GROUP BY some_id, some_date
WITH ROLLUP
```

[Here is a test.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71a73/1)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: No, it will not, I'm not summing the id, I'm just adding 1 :)